# JSON Object from string is not returning string

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get some information out of my JSON object and i keep getting an error on my console saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queue' of undefined".
```

I have this json:

```
{
    "qmd_file": {
        "queue": "rr7323-psp",
        "name": "unicode",
        "full_path": "/devl/data/queue‌​s/psp/rr7323/unicode",
        "mtime": "2015-05-08T19:02:06.000-04:00"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get queue name which is "rr7323-psp". Here is my code:

```
function searchFile (qid, filename) {
  var searchUrl = queue_web_services_base + "/q/v1/find.json?qgid="
                + encodeURIComponent(qid) + "&filename="
                + encodeURIComponent(filename);
  var token = encodeURIComponent(window.bpub.authToken);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: searchUrl,
    headers: {'Authorization' : 'Token token="' + token + '"'},
    success: function(json) {
      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
      obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      console.log(obj.qmd_file[1].queue);
    }
  });

  return searchUrl;
}

self.searchForFile = function() {
  var queueGroup = prompt ("Please eneter Queue group" , "") 
  var fileName = prompt ("Please enter file name: " , "")
  console.log(searchFile(queueGroup, fileName));
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of what the JSON you are loading looks like?

Comment: Hopefully this is what you are asking for: {"qmd_file":{"queue":"rr7323-psp","name":"unicode","full_path":"/devl/data/queues/psp/rr7323/unicode","mtime":"2015-05-08T19:02:06.000-04:00"}}

Comment: json object looks like this:Object {qmd_file: Object}qmd_file: Objectfull_path: "/devl/data/queues/psp/rr7323/unicode"mtime: "2015-05-08T19:02:06.000-04:00"name: "unicode"queue: "rr7323-psp"

Answer (score 1):

You have `obj.qmd_file[1].queue`, but the `qmd_file` node is not an array. `queue` is a direct descendant attribute of `obj.qmd_file`. Try `obj.qmd_file.queue`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the queue element in the JSON with this statement: `obj.qmd_file[1].queue`. This code means "get the 'queue' property of the 2nd object in the 'qmd_file' array in the 'obj' object".

However, in the JSON you posted, "qmd_file" is an object, not an array. Try instead using this code: `obj.qmd_file.queue`

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch it as,

```
console.log(obj.qmd_file.queue);
```

`queue` is a property within the object fetched as `obj.qmd_file` and `qmd_file` is certainly not an array.